# Solving a integro-differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve an integro-differential equation:

$$ {\frac{d}{dt}} f(t)=\int_0^t k(t-\tau)S(\tau)f(\tau)   d\tau $$

with initial condition $f(0)=1$

If $k(t)=c\delta(t)$ with $c$ being constant, the above equation become ODE which is simple to solve.

If $S(t)=c$ with $c$ being constant, the above equation can be solved using Laplace transform.

Without above conditions, however, I do not find any method of solving the equation.

I would like to have the method at least when $S(t)=e^{-at}$  or $S(t)=e^{-at}+e^{-bt}$ with $a$ and $b$ being non-zero positive real valued constant. In such case, Laplace transform yields

$$uF(u)-1=K(u)[F(u+a)+F(u+b)]$$

where $F(u)$ and $K(u)$ respectively represent the Laplace transform of the functions, $f(t)$ and $k(t)$, i.e.,
$$
F(u) = \int_0^\infty e^{-ut}f(t)dt,\quad  K(u) = \int_0^\infty e^{-ut}k(t)dt
$$

Help me if you know any kind of method that solve the above equation. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\partial f(t)/\partial t$?Is it the same as $df(t)/dt$?

Comment: @dodd yes, same. I changed my post for clarification :)

Comment: Also what is $\delta(t)$? The Dirac $\delta$?

Comment: Using Leibniz integral rule repeatedly we can find $f^{(k)}(0)$ . Which then can be used in Taylor series.